# declare and type of array of tuples all of the same form but known at comptime

Tags: zig

How do I make an array of tuples? I have a function that takes an arbitrary function and calls it on every element of them array. Every element will have the same form. I can't declare the type or make an array of tuples.

Comment: A "tuple" in Zig is just a struct. There's no dedicated special type for them (there's the convenience function `std.meta.Tuple` but all that does is construct the struct type for you). Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am being passed a function and using @call on it mutiple times, but I also needs an array of tuples to pass it one at a time. eg for (args) |a| @call(_, func, a). what is the type of  args and how do i create it?

Comment: basically i want to make this simpler: https://github.com/jnordwick/znh/blob/c0988db9ead633f60703cb62631d385b55201707/src/main.zig#L230

Comment: OK, I _think_ I know what you want now, let me just post an answer so you can double check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a "tuple" in Zig is really just a struct where you don't mention any field names. For example, `struct{i32,i32}` is a "tuple" with 2 integer fields.

You can define an array of those the exact same way as you can for any other struct:

```
// 2-element array of i32 pairs
const arr = [_]struct{i32,i32}{.{1,2}, .{3,4}};
```

If you just want to write a function that calls the same function with multiple different sets of args you don't even need to mention the type there, you can just leave it up to the caller to pass in the right args:

```
fn call_multiple(f: anytype, args_array: anytype) void {
    for (args_array) |a| {
        @call(.auto, f, a);
    }
}
```

So imagine we had this:

```
fn sum_and_print(x: i32, y: i32) void {
    std.log.debug("{} + {} = {}", .{ x, y, x + y });
}
```

which you can call like this:

```
    // you can define it inline
    call_multiple(&sum_and_print, &[_]struct { i32, i32 }{ .{ 1, 1 }, .{ 1, 2 }, .{ 2, 3 }, .{ 3, 5 } });

    // or as a separate declaration
    const args = struct { i32, i32 };
    call_multiple(&sum_and_print, &[_]args{ .{ 1, 1 }, .{ 1, 2 }, .{ 2, 3 }, .{ 3, 5 } });
```

You can also use `std.meta.ArgsTuple` to get a tuple type for the args of a function type, which you may be able to use here depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish:

```
fn call_multiple_2(f: anytype, args_array: []const std.meta.ArgsTuple(@TypeOf(f))) void {
    for (args_array) |a| {
        @call(.auto, f, a);
    }
}

call_multiple_2(sum_and_print, &.{ .{ 1, 1 }, .{ 1, 2 }, .{ 2, 3 }, .{ 3, 5 } });
```